# obtener la cantidad de dias entre dos fechas

Tags: sql-server, sql

hola a todos quiero calcular los días que faltan para cumplir una fecha,

ejemplo el día de hoy la fecha es 19/06/2019 y quisiera que me regresara el valor en días para llegar a la fecha 28/06/2019.

esto en sql

Comment: En qué gestor de bases de datos?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En SQL Server tienes desde las primeras versiones la función [`DATEDIFF()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), la sintaxis: `DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )` que en tu ejemplo: obtener la cantidad de días desde hoy al 28 de junio, sería algo así:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF ( dd , GETDATE() , '2019-06-28' )
```

Comment: muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho me ayudo mucho